# Is there an universal printer in OCaml that detect the type?

Tags: ocaml

I want to print  a list with different element in it (for educational purpose)

I have read a tutorial that explain how to store different type in list.

```
type _ list =
    [] : unit list
  | ( :: ) : 'b * 'a list -> ('b ->'a) list;;
1 :: "e" :: 'r' :: [];; (* this is allowed *)
```

how I can do something like this pseudo-code:

```
match typeof(my_expr) with
  int -> print_int
| string -> print_string
```

we will have "1,e,r" printed.
Some solutions i have searched

- Change my type in text and printing it
- Use a different type definition maybe ('a, 'b) list ?

I ask this because the OCaml toplevel know the type of every variable and show always the type in the right format: can I call this printer ?

Is there a solution only for toplevel that we can install with the `#install_printer` ?

I know that compiler discard type's info after the type checking pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printer of the toplevel should work fine:

```
[1; "one"; 1.];;
- : (int -> string -> float -> unit) list =
(::) (1, (::) ("one", (::) (1., [])))
```

(The unoptimal printing is an unfortunate consequence of ensuring that values printed by the toplevel can be copy-pasted back to the top-level and yields the same value)

But this is only possible outside of the language itself: the toplevel printers can inspect the typing environment which is purposefully not possible in the language itself. Indeed functions like `typeof` would break parametricity. There is thus no universal printer function in OCaml (without looking at the internal memory representation) and no universal heterogeneous list printer.

If you want to print an heterogeneous list, there are three possible paths:

- print a specific type of the heterogeneous list

  ```
  let print_concrete ppf (x::y::z::rest) = Format.fprintf ppf "%f %f %f" x y z
  ```

  *(Contrary to appearance, this function is total: its type makes it impossible to use on lists with fewer than three elements)*
- Use heterogeneous lists that always pack a printing function along its main value

  ```
  type 'a printer = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit

  type _ showable_list = 
  | [] : unit showable_list 
  | (::):
    ('a * 'a printer) * 'b showable_list
     -> ('a -> 'b) showable_list

  let rec print: type a. a showable_list printer =
   fun ppf l -> match l with
   | [] -> ()
   | (a,printer) :: rest -> Format.fprintf ppf "%a@ %a" printer a print rest
  ```
- provide a matching heterogeneous list of printing functions

  ```
   type 'a plist = 
   | []: unit plist
   | (::): 'a printer * 'b plist -> ('a -> 'b) plist

   let rec print: type l. l plist -> l list printer = fun printers ppf values ->
   match printers, values with
   | [], [] -> ()
   | p :: prest, a :: rest -> Format.fprintf ppf "%a@ %a" p a (print prest) rest
  ```

The fact that you often need to specialize the heterogeneous list type may make it worthwhile to introduce a functor for generating them:

```
 module Hlist(Specialization: sig type 'a t end) = struct
   open Specialization 
   type 'a list = 
     | []: unit list
     | (::): 'a t * 'b list -> ('a -> 'b) list
   end
```

then the previous specialized type can be constructed with

```
module Showable_list = Hlist(struct type 'a t = 'a * 'a printer end)
module Printer_list = Hlist (struct type 'a t = 'a printer end)
```

Comment: thanks for you answers I agree with the fact that the format that is printed should be copy-pastable. But there is two syntaxe for heterogenous list so `[1; "one"; 1.]`
can be printed like `- : (int -> string -> float -> unit) list = 1 :: "one" :: 1. :: []`
Your first solution is great but I search something that do like the toplevel: because he now the type he can print it (with the constructor form).
the solution 2 and 3 contrary to first solution work for list of all length: but I have to remeber wich type of data I add to the list and add the right printer.

Comment: I have read that both 0 and false have the same internal representation so how can we could build universal printer ? I know also for Variant type the Variant is stored: I have to make a list like that `Int 3 :: Char 'r' :: String "e" :: []`

Comment: How can we inspect typing environnement of the toplevel ? Maybe I could be able to make something magic that do more or less what the toplevel do (it can print any variable including Variant type).

Comment: First, the solution 2 and 3 is similar to what happens with regular list where the list printer takes the element printer as an argument, except that with heterogeneous list each element needs its own printer. Second, you can peek at the memory representation and prints that, see the inspect opam package for instance. Third, if you want you could hack the toplevel code to customize the printing function for those kinds of list, but this cannot work in the language itself: there is no universal printer in OCaml and this is a feature.

Comment: I have read "unit, [], false As OCaml int 0." from  https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html So I can't really hack. Can you give some more hint ?

Comment: You can just use inspect, for instance `Inspect.Sexpr.dump (Obj.repr [1;"one"; []])` yields:`(DUMP (BLK/0 :TAG 0 :VALUES 1
      (BLK/1 :TAG 0 :VALUES (STR/2 :LEN 3 "one") (BLK/3 :TAG 0 :VALUES 0 0))))`

Comment: ~~ `Error: Unbound module Inspect` after `opam install inspect` ... maybe you are a magician. Is it text or other format ? (I can't test) ~~ ok I have to use topfind. It is not a string I have seen the doc http://krohrer.github.io/caml-inspect/doc/inspect/html/Sexpr.html and no function return a string almost all return unit: The light in my eye was turned off.

Comment: `dump_with_formatter` can be used to obtain a string: `Format.asprintf "%a" Inspect.Sexpr.dump_with_formatter (Obj.repr [1;"one"])`